# What .merge() is doing in this query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm a little confused about how to interpret this query, all because of `merge` situation, even after reading the documentation.

I would like to know what is the corresponding SQL query for the below

```
Analise.joins(dape: [empresa: :area_atuacao])
       .merge(@dapes)
       .where(analises: { atual: true })
       .pluck('analises.img')
```

Output from calling `to_sql` on this query:

```
=> "SELECT \"analises\".* 
    FROM \"analises\" 
    INNER JOIN \"dapes\" ON \"dapes\".\"id\" = \"analises\".\"dape_id\" 
    INNER JOIN \"empresas\" ON \"empresas\".\"id\" = \"dapes\".\"empresa_id\" 
    INNER JOIN \"areas_atuacao\" ON \"areas_atuacao\".\"id\" = \"empresas\".\"area_atuacao_id\" 
    WHERE \"analises\".\"atual\" = 't'"
```

Comment: Can you do me a favor and run the code you supplied with the .to_sql command at the end? 

If you understand how to read SQL queries then this might help, but for me to give you concrete answer I could use that out put please.

So just run the following code and let me know the output:
`Analise.joins(dape: [empresa: :area_atuacao]).merge(@dapes).where(analises: { atual: true }).pluck('analises.img').to_sql`

I was able to gather some information for you here, take a look. [Active Record Queries](https://medium.com/rubyinside/active-records-queries-tricks-2546181a98dd)

Comment: => "SELECT \"analises\".* FROM \"analises\" INNER JOIN \"dapes\" ON \"dapes\".\"id\" = \"analises\".\"dape_id\" INNER JOIN \"empresas\" ON \"empresas\".\"id\" = \"dapes\".\"empresa_id\" INNER JOIN \"areas_atuacao\" ON \"areas_atuacao\".\"id\" = \"empresas\".\"area_atuacao_id\" WHERE \"analises\".\"atual\" = 't'"

this was amazing dude !! now I'm able understand, tks !

Comment: I'm confuse with '.merge(@dapes)'
@dapes is ActiveRecord_Relation, but what are doing with the query ?

Comment: Read my answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

> **merge(other)**
>   Merges in the conditions from other, if other is an ActiveRecord::Relation.
>   - [Rails API Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)

A common example is using it for example to merge search conditions together:

```
@cities = City.all
@cities = @cities.merge(City.where(country: params[:country])) if params[:country]
@cities = @cities.merge(City.where(name: params[:name])) if params[:name]
```

You can also use it to create conditions on joined tables like in this example from the docs:

```
Post.where(published: true)
    .joins(:comments)
    .merge( Comment.where(spam: false) )
```

This creates the same query as:

```
Post.where(published: true)
    .joins(:comments)
    .where(comments: { spam: false })
```

The exact query in you example depends on the scope defined in the instance variable `@dapes`. But judging from the SQL generated `.merge(@dapes)` seems to do nothing. This could be the case if `@dapes = Dape.all` for example.

Merging a condition with no where clause does nothing:

```
irb(main):003:0> User.merge(User.all)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your formatted better for a better readability. The merge is used to transfer over your conditions so that nothing gets overriden.

```
SELECT analises.* 
FROM analises
    INNER JOIN dapes ON dapes.id = analises.dape_id
    INNER JOIN empresas ON empresas.id = dapes.empresa_id
    INNER JOIN areas_atuacao ON areas_atuacao.id = empresas.area_atuacao_id
WHERE analises.atual = 't'
```

It seems `.merge()` is used when you are joining tables to be more specific of what exactly you are joining.

In this case you are `.merge(@dapes)` seems to be merging your tables on all values of `@dapes`.

One way to get a better understanding of what impact .merge(@dapes) is having on your query is to run the `to_sql` command again how the sql has changed.

## Footnote

I took the sql that was generated from the first `to_sql` you ran and entered it into the Scuttle Editor and got the following rails commands. I don't know if this helps but I just thought it was food for thought!

```
Analise.select(Analise.arel_table[Arel.star]).where(Analise.arel_table[:atual].eq('t')).joins(
  Analise.arel_table.join(Dape.arel_table).on(
    Dape.arel_table[:id].eq(Analise.arel_table[:dape_id])
  ).join_sources
).joins(
  Analise.arel_table.join(Empresa.arel_table).on(
    Empresa.arel_table[:id].eq(Dape.arel_table[:empresa_id])
  ).join_sources
).joins(
  Analise.arel_table.join(AreasAtuacao.arel_table).on(
    AreasAtuacao.arel_table[:id].eq(Empresa.arel_table[:area_atuacao_id])
  ).join_sources
)
```

Comment: I can't really see that its doing anything at all. `.joins(dape: [empresa: :area_atuacao])` is creating the nested joins and there is nothing actually being selected from the `dapes` table  or any conditions on it. Also I believe `.pluck` will override the select clause of the query anyways.

Comment: No. Pluck overrides the select clause to return a single column. `User.all.pluck(:name) => SELECT users.name FROM "users" => array`. Thats kind of the point - to create a effective query for a single column instead of instanciating a bunch of objects